# Implementing Enqueue and Dequeue without built-in methods

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, queue

I have two functions one to dequeue and one to enqueue a user-inputted item from/to an array respectively.

**What I know about queues**

What I know about queues is pretty limited, I know they are similar to stacks but rather than being Last-In-First-Out (LIFO) as stacks are they are First-In-First-Out (FIFO) so basically whatever elements go into the array first will be taken out of the array first.

**What I am trying right now**

What I am trying to do right now is with the `Enqueue` button I am adding items to an array while incrementing the variable count by 1 with each push of the button so as to add each new user input to the next array position. In the dequeue function, I am setting each element of the `dequeue` array equal to each element of the original array by incrementing the `dequeueCount` variable.

**What is the problem**
The problem here is this, when I push the dequeue button I basically need to reindex everything so that after I dequeue an element the element at index 1, now takes the position index 0 and basically I always want to dequeue the item at element 0.

**queue.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-queue',
  templateUrl: './queue.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./queue.component.css']
})
export class QueueComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() userInput: String 
  array = []
  arrayCount = 0
  dequeueCount = 0
  dequeueArray = []
  dequeued = null

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  enQ() {
    this.array[this.arrayCount++] = this.userInput;

  }

  deQ() {
    deQ() {
    if (this.arrayCount > 0) {
    this.dequeueArray[this.dequeueCount++] = this.array[this.dequeueCount-1]
    this.dequeued = this.dequeueArray[this.dequeueCount-1]
    this.arrayCount--
    }
    else {
      this.dequeued = "There is nothing else to dequeue"
    }

  }
}
```

and I am trying to show the current value of the array here

```html
<div>
  <label for="userInput">Input to Array:
    <input [(ngModel)]="userInput" type="text">
  </label><br>
  <button (click)="enQ()">Enqueue</button>
  <button (click)="deQ()">Dequeue</button>

  <h3>Arrays</h3>
  <p *ngFor = "let item of array"> {{ array }} </p>

  <h3>Dequeued Item</h3>
  <p> {{ dequeued}} </p>
</div>
```

when I press the enqueue function everything seems to work correctly and a value is added to the array at the correct position so no problems with the enqueue function, however with the dequeue function, I need to somehow be able to dequeue the items and also remove the first item from the array and redisplay `{{ array }}` with the dequeued item removed.

Comment: for those who are telling me the approach is complicated, i am aware it is, this is based off  a task that has been set for me to enqueue and dequeue using only an array, a count and an index, without the use of built in functions such as push, shift, etc

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is complicated and vague, I made a new one based on your intention.

Even if this code doesn't match your needs, at least you can start from this one.

**queue.component.ts**

```ts
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @Input() userInput;
  array = [];
  arrayCount = 0;
  dequeuedCount = 0;
  dequeued;

  get queue() {
    const q = [];
    for (let i = this.dequeuedCount; i < this.arrayCount; i++) {
      q[i - this.dequeuedCount] = this.array[i];
    }
    return q;
  }

  enQ() {
    this.array[this.arrayCount++] = this.userInput;
  }

  deQ() {
    if (this.arrayCount > this.dequeuedCount) {
      this.dequeued = this.array[this.dequeuedCount++];
    } else {
      this.dequeued = "There is nothing else to dequeue";
    }
  }
}
```

**queue.component.html**

```html
<div>
  <label for="userInput">Input to Array:
    <input [(ngModel)]="userInput" type="text">
  </label><br>
  <button (click)="enQ()">Enqueue</button>
  <button (click)="deQ()">Dequeue</button>

  <h3>Arrays</h3>
  <p> {{ queue | json }} </p>

  <h3>Dequeued Item</h3>
  <p> {{ dequeued | json }} </p>
</div>
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bt8ufd

Comment: its complicated intentionally because the goal is to implement enqueueing and dequeueing using only an array and a count just to get a better understanding of how those functions work and how queues work

Comment: @Banani720 Ok, I've updated my post. I'm not sure using `Array.prototype.slice` is right though.

Comment: So technically `.slice()` works but gives the function an O(n) time complexity right?

Comment: The hint I was given is that I would need two indexes in this scenario to do it with a linear time complexity

Comment: @Banani720 I mean I'm not sure using it is appropriate if your original goal is to understand how it works under the hood.

Comment: Right that’s the objective here I thought I had it but was told basically not to use helper methods

Comment: I will probably have to rework how I’m getting around to this

Comment: I've updated the question a little bit I feel like I am coming close but I am very much wrong somewhere in my code

Comment: @Banani720 I think I've understood your needs. See updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Try the snippet, it should solve the problem.

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]  
})
export class AppComponent {
  userInput: String;

  array = [];
  dequeued = [];

  enQ() {
    this.array.push(this.userInput);
  }

  deQ() {
    if (this.array.length > 0) {
      this.dequeued.push(this.array[this.array.length - 1]);
      this.array.shift();
    }
  }
}


<div>
   <label for="userInput">Input to Array:
   <input [(ngModel)]="userInput" type="text">
   </label><br>
   <button (click)="enQ()">Enqueue</button>
   <button (click)="deQ()">Dequeue</button>

   <h3>Arrays</h3>
   <p> {{ array |json}} </p>

   <h3>Dequeued Item</h3>
   <p> {{ dequeued|json}} </p>
</div>
```

In your code you missing the `pipe` on `dequeue` variable, so when it hold the array the values will not be rendered by angular

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yldzgl)

Comment: this works, I probably should've worded my question better, I have edited the title and updated the question text accordingly hopefully it makes more sense now, I can't use any built-in functions